# Filter with match_all VS query

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have 2 types of queries. They are both logically identical however I'm not sure if there is any performance difference between the two.

I will be glad if someone can enlighten me.

Using `match_all` and `filter`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "user_id": "1234567"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "ephoc_date": {
                  "lt": 1437033590,
                  "gte": 1437026390
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Using `term` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "user_id": "1234567"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "ephoc_date": {
                  "lt": 1437033590,
                  "gte": 1437026390
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your query it seems like you don't care about how documents are scored based on the value of `user_id` field being "1234567". What I mean to say is - If more than one document have `user_id` set to "1234567", you don't care about the order of documents in the result. If that is the case, 2nd option is better with respect to performance because there is some computation cost associated with scoring in the 1st query while there is no scoring in the 2nd query. By the way, your 2nd query can also be simplified to below:

```
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "term": {
                  "user_id": "1234567"
               }
            },
            {
               "range": {
                  "ephoc_date": {
                     "lt": 1437033590,
                     "gte": 1437026390
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But isn't `match_all` query expensive in terms of performance? Doesn't it load the whole documents before applying the `filter` to them?

Comment: It doe not work the way you think it does. Filters are executed first to get the matching set of documents. It is on this set of documents that `query` works on.

Comment: does the simplify query you suggested is exact in performance as my 2nd query which both are better then the 1st query ?

Comment: Yes the simplified query is exactly the same in performance as your 2nd query.